# Data Envelopment Analysis (DEA): how to linearize a formulation?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Following a [basic example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_envelopment_analysis#Example), I'd appreciate some help in understanding how the formulation was linearized. Would appreciate if someone could write it out explicitly. I understand the denominator of the objective function (OF) was set to 1. (If I understand correctly, this is the only substitution required to make all transformations).

$$10v_1+2v_2 = 1$$

So, using this substitution, the OF can be converted to a linear form

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Non-linear} && \text{Linear} \\
\\
\frac{100u_1}{10v_1+2v_2} && 100u_1
\end{align}
$$

And the same with the corresponding efficiency constraint for this unit:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Non-linear} && && \text{Linear} \\
\\
\frac{100u_1}{10v_1+2v_2}\leqslant 1 && && 100u_1 - (10v_1+2v_2)\leqslant 0
\end{align}
$$

But how are the efficiency constraints of other units converted when their denominators are not equal to 1?

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Non-linear} && && \text{Linear} \\
\\
\frac{80u_1}{8v_1+4v_2}\leqslant 1 && && 80u_1 - (8v_1+4v_2)\leqslant 0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the non-linear inequality:
$$\frac{80u_1}{8v_1+4v_2}\leq 1 \Rightarrow 80u_1\leq 8v_1+4v_2 \Rightarrow 80u_1-(8v_1+4v_2)\leq 0.$$
The above is straight forward.
Now consider the linear inequality on the RHS
$$80u_1-(8v_1+4v_2)\leq 0 \Rightarrow 80u_1\leq 8v_1+4v_2 \Rightarrow \frac{80u_1}{8v_1+4v_2}\leq 1$$
This implication holds true under the assumption that the denominator term $8v_1+4v_2 \neq 0.$ We can show that it is indeed true, by solving the following two linear inequalities:
$$8v_1+4v_2 = 0 \text{ and } 10v_1+2v_2=1.$$
On solving, we get $v_2<0$ (Not possible). Hence, our assumption holds true.  Similarly, we can show for other inequality also. Hope this helps.